# Objective-C repeated rows from parse object

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I've been stuck on this problem for a while now. Basically i've been trying to pull a list of results from parse and then get information from a relational pointer.

I have got to the point where i can set the cells label to the title but it seems to have the same title for as many rows are returned.

I know i need to utilize the indexPath.row somewhere but i can't for the life of me think how.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated :)

```
   //
//  DEMOWatchedGamesTableViewController.m
//  ShoutOutz
//
//  Created by Craig Turner on 05/08/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Roman Efimov. All rights reserved.
//

#import "DEMOWatchedGamesTableViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface DEMOWatchedGamesTableViewController ()

@end

NSMutableArray *arrayGames;

@implementation DEMOWatchedGamesTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    //PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"watched_games"];



    // Include the user data with each post
    [query includeKey:@"game_id"];


    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *postObjects, NSError *error)
     {
         if(!error){

             NSLog(@"myArray: %@", postObjects);


             self.myArray = postObjects;

             [self.tableView reloadData];


         } else {
             NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
         }

     }];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.myArray count];
    //return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }


    NSLog(@"Array: %@", self.myArray);

    for (PFObject * postObject in self.myArray) {


        [postObject fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error){

            PFObject *postAuthor = [object objectForKey:@"game_id"];


            NSLog(@"retrieved related Post Author: %@", postAuthor);

            cell.textLabel.text = [postAuthor objectForKey:@"gameTitle"];


        }];
    }

    return cell;
}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/


@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rememer that the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method is called once for every cell that needs to be displayed, and that's determined by the value you supply in the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` data source method, in this case - the size of your `myArray` array.

So based on that principle you dont need to go through your array for every iteration of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. What's helpful with this method is that it lets you know which cell index it is going to create by supplying you the `indexPath`. So you can use this `indexPath` value supplied by the method as an index to then grab the appropriate instance in your array like so:

This is just an example based on your existing code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    /**
      Why are you printing the array? youll end up printing it as many times as there are instances
      in your myArray array. You dont want to do that ;)
      NSLog(@"Array: %@", self.myArray);
    */

    //Using the indexpath's row value we can go ahead and grab that from your myArray array
    PFObject * postObject = [self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [postObject fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error){
        PFObject *postAuthor = [object objectForKey:@"game_id"];
        NSLog(@"retrieved related Post Author: %@", postAuthor);
        cell.textLabel.text = [postAuthor objectForKey:@"gameTitle"];
    }];
    return cell;
}
```